# How to search for string in SQL treating apostrophe and single quote as equal

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have a database where our customer has typed "Bob's" one time and "Bob’s" another time. (Note the slight difference between the single-quote and apostrophe.)

When someone searches for "Bob's" or "Bob’s", I want to find all cases regardless of what they used for the apostrophe.

The only thing I can come up with is looking at people's queries and replacing every occurrence of one or the other with `(’|'')`  (Note the escaped single quote) and using SIMILAR TO.

```
SELECT * from users WHERE last_name SIMILAR TO 'O(’|'')Dell'
```

Is there a better way, ideally some kind of setting that allows these to be interchangeable?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [regexp matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

```
with a_table(str) as (
values
    ('Bob''s'),
    ('Bob’s'),
    ('Bobs')
)
select *
from a_table
where str ~ 'Bob[''’]s';

  str  
-------
 Bob's
 Bob’s
(2 rows)
```

Personally I would replace all apostrophes in a table with one query (I had the same problem in one of my projects).

Comment: Thanks. Is there any advantage to this over "SIMILAR TO"?

Comment: See [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions in PostgreSQL](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions-in-postgresql/10696#10696)

Answer (score 0):

If you find that both of the cases above are valid and present the same information then you might actually consider taking care of your data before it arrives into the database for later retrieval. That means you could effectively replace one sign into another within your application code or `before insert` trigger.

If you have more cases like the one you've mentioned then specifying just `LIKE` queries would be a way to go, unfortunately.

You could also consider hints for your customer while creating another user that would fetch up records from database and return closest matches if there are any to avoid such problems.

I'm afraid there is no setting that makes two of these symbols the same in DQL of Postgres. At least I'm not familiar with one.

Comment: I hate manipulating data that is entered, especially since we have multiple languages involved and there may be cases where the user actually wants one over the other. I was hoping for a "treat apostrophes like single-quotes" setting, but not surprised it does not exist.

Comment: Whether you use SIMILAR TO, LIKE or REGEX matching you will still have to write them both. You could also wrap this up within your function and create a functional index :-)